# how to find the total marks in android

Tags: android

Hi In this code finding the total marks and setting the value into textView.But it showing last value and output showing 65.Based on marks I want to find the total marks of the student 
Can any one please help me.

**java**

```
  total_marks=new int[numOfStudents];
        addHeader();
        int j = 0;
        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            subject[j] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
            subject[j].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Maxmarks[j] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.max_mark);
            Maxmarks[j].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Minmarks[j] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.min_mark);
            Minmarks[j].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ObtainedMarks[j] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.obtained_mark);
            ObtainedMarks[j].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Grades[j] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade);
            Grades[j].setVisibility(View.GONE);

            StudentgradeDetails p = (StudentgradeDetails) i.next();
            tr = new TableRow(this);


            subject[j] = new EditText(this);
            subject[j].setKeyListener(null);
            subject[j].setText(p.getSubject());
            subject[j].setId(p.getId());
            subject[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            subject[j].setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);

            Ll.addView(subject[j], params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            Maxmarks[j] = new EditText(this);

            Maxmarks[j].setKeyListener(null);
            Maxmarks[j].setText(p.getMaxMark());
            Maxmarks[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Maxmarks[j].setPadding(2,2, 2, 2);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);

            Ll.addView(Maxmarks[j], params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            Minmarks[j] = new EditText(this);
            Minmarks[j].setKeyListener(null);
            Minmarks[j].setText(p.getMinMark());
            Minmarks[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Minmarks[j].setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(Minmarks[j], params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            ObtainedMarks[j] = new EditText(this);
            ObtainedMarks[j].setKeyListener(null);
            ObtainedMarks[j].setText(p.getObtainedMark());
            ObtainedMarks[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            ObtainedMarks[j].setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(ObtainedMarks[j], params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            Grades[j] = new EditText(this);
            Grades[j].setKeyListener(null);


                 int marks1 =Integer.parseInt(ObtainedMarks[j].getText().toString());
                 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                String grade=Integer.toString(marks1);
                 if(marks1 >= 80){
                     grade="A+";
                 } else if(marks1>=70){
                     grade="A";  
                     }   
                 else if(marks1>=60){
                     grade="B+";     
                     }   
                 else if(marks1>=50){
                     grade="B";  
                     }
                 else if(marks1>=40){
                     grade="C";  
                     }
                 else{
                     return; 
                 }
                 Grades[j].setText(grade);

                 try {

                        total_marks[j]+=marks1;
                        TotalMarks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);

                        TotalMarks.setText("Total Marks:"+total_marks[j]);
                 }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                 }  
            Grades[j].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Grades[j].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(Grades[j], params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            j++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
    int total_marks=0;

    int marks1 =Integer.parseInt(ObtainedMarks[j].getText().toString());
    total_marks+=marks1;
    TotalMarks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);

    TotalMarks.setText("Total Marks:"+total_marks);
```